# intel realsense F200 camera recover uncompressed images?

Tags: c++, intel, realsense

I am working on a project in C++ where I need to capture high quality images from Intel Realsense F200 cameras. I was able to stream the high resolution color (1920 x 1080) and capture one frame and save it in binary file in the hard disk to be used later with other tools in Matlab.  But I was unable to get the high resolution images as expected; and was finding several block like artifacts in the image. Note that I am not using any image compression utility to compress the images. Is it because the captured frames acquired by the camera are compressed by default and that's why after saving it on disk, I am getting the compressed version, or it it because of something else?? If I am getting the compressed version of the image. What can be done to uncompress the image and get the full definition image. Please note that I am capturing still images, not the video stream which is supposedly seems to be the common thing.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Saif.

Comment: How about showing us an example of what the image looks like.  Are you sure you are interpreting the colour encoding correctly?  If it's coming from a raw sensor, the encoding might be Bayer instead of RGB.  Also, you might have issues with endianness.

Comment: What format are you saving the images in?

Comment: I am saving it in png format.